# Get last non null value columnwise where column is sorted by date

Tags: sql, postgresql

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/49018b/1)

```
select *
from example;

edate   userid  status
2022-05-01  abc123  true
2022-05-02  abc123  (null)
2022-05-03  abc123  (null)
2022-05-04  abc123  (null)
2022-05-05  abc123  false
2022-05-06  abc123  (null)
2022-05-07  abc123  (null)
2022-05-08  abc123  (null)
2022-05-09  abc123  true
2022-05-10  abc123  (null)
```

I want to write a new field, 'status_backfilled' based on the most recent data point for a userId.

In the example data, The users status is true on May 1st, then null untill May 5th. So, I would like the new field to be true between May 1st till May 4th. Then the status switches to false. This value is unchanged till May 9th, so I want false between May 5th till 8th, then true again.

Desired output:

```
select *
from example_desired;

edate   userid  status_backfilled
2022-05-01  abc123  true
2022-05-02  abc123  true
2022-05-03  abc123  true
2022-05-04  abc123  true
2022-05-05  abc123  false
2022-05-06  abc123  false
2022-05-07  abc123  false
2022-05-08  abc123  false
2022-05-09  abc123  true
2022-05-10  abc123  true
```

How can I columnwise coalesce to get the most recent non null status for a user where data are sorted, in this case by date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually, even better :

```
select e1.edate, e1.userId, coalesce(e1.status, t.status) as status
from example e1
cross join lateral ( 
   select status from example e2 
   where e1.userid = e2.userid 
   and e1.edate > e2.edate 
   and e2.status is not null 
   order by e2.edate desc limit 1 
 ) t
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/49018b/66)

here is another way :

```
with cte as (
  select e.* ,e_s.edate s_edate, e_s.status s_status , row_number() over (partition by e.userid,e.edate order by e_s.edate desc) rn  
  from example e
  left join (
    select * 
    from example
    where status is not null 
  ) e_s on e.userid = e_s.userid 
        and e_s.edate < e.edate 
) 

select edate, userId, coalesce(status, s_status) as status
from cte where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your desired result by using a few window functions -

```
WITH grp AS (SELECT edate, userid, status,
                    CASE WHEN status IS NULL THEN 0
                         ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY edate)
                     END RN
               FROM example
           ),
grp_sum AS (SELECT edate, userid, status, SUM(RN) OVER(ORDER BY edate) grp_sum
              FROM grp
           )
SELECT edate, userid,
       FIRST_VALUE(status) OVER(PARTITION BY grp_sum ORDER BY status NULLS LAST) status_backfilled 
  FROM grp_sum;
```

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/49018b/52)